# How can I hide tabs while scrolling down a ListView then show them again if the user scrolls up?

Tags: android

I want to make the tabs of a tabhost fade up if the user is scrolling down a listview

I have the following code but it does not work

```
ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ls.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }
            int previousVisible = 3;
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (previousVisible < firstVisibleItem) {
                    getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost)
                            .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost)
                            .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                previousVisible = firstVisibleItem;
            }
        });
```

Comment: May be fake tab is suitable. Add fake tabhost in headerview of listview.

Comment: @Yul That would mean the user would have to scroll all the way to the top to see the tabs again

Comment: So you can elaborate what you want in the question. When you want show and hide tabhost.

Comment: Hi code578841441, have got any good answer for Ur question, i need to implement the same in my on going app..Please reply

Comment: please post if someone does have a answer

Comment: @code578841441  have u found solution ? pls share

Answer (score 1):

Lars Werkman has implemented an Android Library to implement this UI principle from Roman Nurik and Nick Butcher.

https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView

Comment: Great but this lib seems not maintained

Comment: I am hoping Google wil add someting to the support libraries. They use a variant of this pattern in the Google Play Market app and the G+ app. It seems to be an "emerging" UI pattern.