# Hidden view above existing view that contains a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

As per screen 1, I have one Title view, and a listview below it,
I want to place a 'hidden view' above this 'title view' which will be visible only when I have scrolled this list till the top.   [image: First] [image: second]

I have seen [Hide your actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500353/android-actionbar-hide-show-when-scrolling-list-view)
and [QuickReturnListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824508/android-scroll-up-hide-view-and-scroll-down-show-view-effect-like-twitter) and ObservableScrollView

but as I understand none of them serves my purpose. Do anybody know how to achieve something like this?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: It shows the top bar as soon as I scroll down, I want it to show only when I have reached to the top of the list

Comment: It has 9 combinations right! This option is what you need.. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/master/samples/images/demo6.gif

Comment: As I said in my previous comment 'it shows the hidden view as soon as I 'start' scrolling down, while I want to show the hidden view only when my list has reached to the top item'

Comment: check android design support, it matches your need and a simple one.
http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

You made one of the awesome question. I will just suggest creating one custom layout which will get added into the header of the ListView, and that custom layout contains these two views one is always 'visible' and other view in default 'gone' mode and while the time of refresh makes it 'visible'. or you can use addHeader method while on start and end refresh.

```
    listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

I hope this suggestion will work, "*Best of Luck...!!*"

*"Happy Coding...!!!"*